# Filtrar lista jquery datatble no evento enter

Tags: jquery-datatables, datatable

Quanto instancio: `myTable = $('#dynamicTableDesc').DataTable();`

Ao tentar chamar a função:  `myTable.fnFilter(this.value);` da **erro** `myTable.fnFilter is not a function` e ao chamar: `myTable.ajax.reload();` **funciona perfeitamente**.

Já quando instacio: `myTable = $('#dynamicTableDesc').dataTable();`
Com **d** minúsculo.

Ao tentar chamar a função:  `myTable.fnFilter(this.value);` **funciona** e ao chamar: `myTable.ajax.reload();` **não funciona**.

O que devo fazer para fazer funcionar?

Código Completo:

```
    myTable = $('#dynamicTableDesc').DataTable({
                    sAjaxSource: "/@controller/List",
                    bServerSide: true,
                    bPaginate: true,
                    pageLength: 50,
                    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
                    buttons: [
                        //{ extend: 'copy' },
                        //{ extend: 'csv' },
                        { extend: 'excel', title: '@titulo' },
                        { extend: 'pdf', title: '@titulo' },
                        {
                            extend: 'print',
                            customize: function (win) {
                                $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                                $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                                $(win.document.body).find('table').addClass('compact').css('font-size', 'inherit');
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    aoColumnDefs: [
                            { bSortable: false, aTargets: [-1] },
                            { bSearchable: false, aTargets: [-1] },
                            {
                                mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                                    var id = data;
                                    var html = "";
                                    html += "<a href='/@controller/Details/" + id + "' title='Visualizar' class='detalhes @classDetails'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></a>";
                                    html += "<a href='/@controller/Edit/" + id + "?&ex=1' title='Alterar' class='alterar @classEdit'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a>";
                                    html += "<a href='javascript:;' title='Deletar' class='deletar @classDel' data-rel='" + id + "," + row[0].replace(",", "") + ",@controller,Del'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>";
                                    return html;
                                },
                                aTargets: [-1]
                            }
                    ],
                    fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                        $(nRow).attr("id", aData[aData.length - 1]);
                        return nRow;
                    }

                });
                $('.dataTables_filter input')
                    .unbind()
                    .bind('keyup',
                    function (e) {
                        if (this.value.length == 0) {
                            myTable.fnFilter('');
                        } else {
                            if (this.value.length >= 3 && e.keyCode == 13) {
                                myTable.fnFilter(this.value);
                            }
                        }
                    });

myTable.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: Coloque mais sobre seu código. Você está tentando fazer um filtro através de um campo `input` ?

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza como citei, meu problema esta sendo na instancia do DataTable. O filtro funciona se eu instanciar ele com d minusculo, mas o reload para de funcionar. Se eu instanciar com D maiúsculo o reload funciona mas a busca não funciona.

Comment: quando pedimos para que de mais detalhes sobre o código, é porque temos que analisar como ele esta sendo usado pois não tem como adivinha as coisas, mais mesmo assim vou chutar uma resposta independente de estar errada.

Comment: Desculpe.. postei o código todo!

Comment: Creio que a resposta seja a solução

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Na verdade, a confusão aqui é sobre a diferença entre $().dataTable() que você está usando e retorna um objeto jQuery e a antiga DataTables API e $().DataTable() que retorna a nova instância da API. ( Tradução livre )
>
> Fonte: [Forum DataTables](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20817/table-ajax-reload-is-undefined) em Inglês

Sabendo-se isso, para que o método `reload()` funcione chame do seguinte jeito:

```
myTAble.api().ajax.reload();
```

Veja que no [manual](https://datatables.net/manual/api#Accessing-the-API) ao lado direito há uma **Nota de atualização** explicando a diferença entre as versões.

Comment: Perfeito cara. obrigado!